# Is there any way to disable TLS in hadoop gcs connector?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc, envoyproxy

I am trying to use Envoy proxy to proxy all the hadoop gcs connector requests to google storage/auth servers. As per the logs I can see GCS connector uses https. So when I use Envoy proxy it doesn't work as there is some issue in CONECT call handshake. Is there any way to disable the client side SSL? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think just disabling client side SSL is an option here as GCS will then in turn fail your requests. Envoy proxy seems to support SSL passthrough.

Comment: I just want the client to Envoy call to be non-SSL. Envoy to storage can be a SSL call. Could you please point me to the docs which shows how to configure SSL passthrough. For me it is not working after multiple attempts. Thanks.

Comment: Just did some online search around this myself and not expert on Envoy. But again I don't think you can disable ssh on client side, at least not at GCS connector level. You might want to find assist in Envoy community for any workaround (personally would be surprised if they don't support ssh).